# Getting Error while using Convert(DateTime,'1750-12-07') in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Getting error while using

```
Convert(DateTime, '1750-12-07')
```

in SQL Server 2012

**ERROR**:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `DATETIME` has a valid range of 01-01-1753 through 31-12-9999 .....

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Convert(DateTime2,'1750-12-07') 

Datetime Range from 1753 to 9999
Datetime2 Range from 0001 to 9999
```